# ASP Net MVC 4 deployment package miss necessary items

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Deployment setting is "Only files needed to run this application". It always miss Home views, and Many Many Many CSS files, like bootstrap.css.

Is there any way I can customize the package easily? I know it is possible to use the XML file to exclude the files manually, but it is annoying to write included XML files since there are so many files

Comment: How are these missing files referenced by your project?

Comment: I install the bootstrap manually by adding items and change the bundleconfig

Comment: Are they actually referenced as content by the project? Or were they put into a folder and referenced in the bundle config only?